# Get actual name of another AWS Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have two lambda functions defined where the `BFunction` function is supposed to call `AFunction`:

```
Resources:
  AFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
...
  BFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
...
```

After deployment, the functions get a random unique identifier like `XYZ-AFunction-<some number>`, which I use to invoke the function:

```
lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda')

lambda_client.invoke(
    FunctionName="XYZ-AFunction-<some number>",
    InvocationType=invocation_type,
    Payload=json.dumps(payload),
)
```

So at the moment, I do a deployment, go to the AWS console, grab the assigned identifier, paste it in the code, and do another deployment. Is there a way to get this unique identifier via code?

Comment: Either give Function A a specific name or use a [ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-function.html#sam-resource-function-return-values) to Function A's name as the value for an [environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-function.html#sam-function-environment) variable that you set on Function B. I'd go with the latter.